# How to find any 10% drop for a certain period?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This task is overwhelming for me.
I have a db with :

```
subject  date value
A        UNIX  6
B        UNIX  2
D        UNIX  4
A        UNIX  7
B        UNIX  9
```

Where each `subject` is a different *time series* with all dates of the year and values. (so each subject contain all unix dates)

I need to find for `subject` `A` and `C`, when did they dropped 10% in `value`.
or:

> during 2020 find when A or C fall 10% in value

I would usually use `lag` with a **window** like:

```
LAG(value,5) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_num)
```

but this will help to find a *slop* based on a certain *window*.

I need to find the 10% slop on **any** possible window between certain dates, and **get the first time** we have a 10% drop (in case it kept falling to 20%).

Comment: In my proposed solution there were several typos. Edited my answer in order to fix them.

Comment: You actually want to look at all possible ranges of dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will anchor your "drops" to each possible starting date and then return only the first successive date where the value had fallen relative to the anchor. If such drops occurs for different anchor dates they'll all be returned. There won't be checks to see if there are overlaps in those date ranges.

```
select t1.subject, t1.dt as date1, min(t2.dt) as date2
from T t1 inner join T t2
    on t2.subject = t1.subject and t2.dt > t1.dt
        and t2.value <= 0.9 * t1.value
where t1.subject in ('A', 'C')
group by t1.subject, t1.dt
```

A lateral join works pretty well to get all the values back:

```
select t1.subject, t1.dt as date1, date2, t1.value as value1, t2.value2,
    (t1.value - value2) * 1.0 / t1.value as pct
from T t1 inner join lateral (
    select distinct
        min(t2.dt) over () as date2,
        first_value(t2.value) over (order by t2.dt) as value2
    from T t2
    where t2.subject = t1.subject and t2.dt > t1.dt and t2.value <= 0.9 * t1.value
) t2 on true
where t1.subject in ('A', 'C')
order by t1.subject, t1.dt
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=abe57498a15abcb53794818f32ae444e

Comment: You will also need to ensure that there are no records with the same subject between t1 and t2, imagine if there is indeed an 11% difference between t1 and t2, but it is a smooth change and there were some in-between records of t3, t4, t5, which were later than t1 and earlier than t2 with the same subject, none of the consequent pairs having a difference of more than 10%.

Comment: @Lajos The question doesn't state anything about consecutive dates. We don't even know what kinds of dates these are. It says "any possible window".

Comment: Imagine a sequence of prices, maybe the prices of bread in each month. If this month the price of bread decreased by 1% in comparison to the last month, we say that the price decreased by 1%, even if it dropped by 15% from its value a year ago. Your query says that this month the price of bread decreased by 15 percent, even though it dropped by 1% from its previous value. The question is not explicit about it, but you can infer these rules based on the schema.

Comment: @Lajos I can infer nothing where there aren't even legitimate dates. As stated above I refer to "any possible window". The mention of `lag(..., 5)` also suggests non-consecutive dates. The query does exactly what I intended. Perhaps it's not what OP actually wants. That for OP to come back and clarify.

Comment: thanks a lot, both of you. dates are -all days of the year- excluding weekends and holidays, like a normal calendar, sorry for being so vague!

Comment: what if I want to ask if it's larger OR smaller than 10%? adding AND > 0.1*t1.value will not work. (check for decrease OR increases in 10%)

Comment: @baltiturg You'll have to clarify. I'm not sure what "it" refers to.

Comment: If the question was "find decrease OR increase of 10%" , currently it's only a decrease. I tried (t2.value <= 0.9 * t1.value OR t2.value >= 0.1 * t1.value). It didn't work.

Comment: even if I asked when we have increase of 10%, this : t2.close >= 0.3 * t1.close  will also not work, not sure why.

Comment: `(t2.value <= 0.9 * t1.value OR 0.9 * t2.value >= t1.value)` The pct calculation in some of the samples would return negative in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
select yt2.subject, min(yt2.date)
from yourtable yt1
join yourtable yt2
on yt1.subject = yt2.subject and
   yt1.date < yt2.date and
   0.9 * yt1.value >= yt2.value
left join yourtable nonexistent
on yt1.subject = nonexistent.subject and
   yt1.date < nonexistent.date and
   nonexistent.date < yt2.date
where yt1.subject in ('A', 'C') and
      nonexistent.subject is null
group by y2.subject;
```

Explanation:

- we join `yt1` and `yt2` to have pairs of the same subject where 10% of the value dropped
- we also join a hypothetical record, called `nonexistent` that has the same `subject` and whose `date` is between the `date` of `yt1` and `yt2`, to see whether there is any change between the two
- in the `where` clause we ensure that `nonexistent` is nonexistent indeed
- we also ensure that the `subject` is in the set we are interested about
- we `group by y2.subject` to get the separate values and aggregate in the `select` clause accordingly

Comment: wow! thanks a lot. but what is the nonexistent ? what do I put there ? :) is this find ALL drops or only 1 ?

Comment: The "nonexistent" join is to make sure the dates are consecutive. It would be easier to just use `lag()/lead()` if that's a requirement.